Azure ADLS how to control file download permissions at folder level
I am struggling with RBAC and ACL permissions for ADLS2. We would like to be able to control who can and cant download files in each of the top folders in an ADLS2 container.
MS Co-Pilot's response says it is not possible as download permissions are defined at a container level using an RBAC role (storage blob data contributor)
Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

According to this

If a user has read permission on blob then he/she will be able to download the blob.

Then remove read access to the user. Means if a user has assigned to storage blob data contributor role or storage blob data reader, then remove the role as shown below:

Then user will restrict to download the blob file. For more information you can refer to the document.
